# How to make responsive video in html?

Tags: html, css, video, responsive-design

So I searched up how to make a video responsive in html with css but it doesn't work. please help

this is my HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <video width="540px" height="320px" controls src="Videos/Video.mp4"></video>
</div>
```

and this is css

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
video {
  height: auto !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean responsive?

Comment: "Responsive" means "adapts to different display sizes" but you need to be specific about **how** you want it to adapt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would erase the `width` and `height` attributes from the `video` tag and (if the video isn't larger than specified by those attribute values) introduce a `max-width` setting in the CSS rule:

```
<div class="container">
   <video controls src="Videos/Video.mp4"></video>
</div>



.container {
  width: 100%;
}
video {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 540px;
}
```

This will make the video either 540px wide if the container is >= than 540px, and make it full width when the container is less than 540px wide. Height will be auto according to the proportions in both cases.

In any case, if your video *is*  larger than specified, you should use the original size width as the value for the `max-width` in the CSS. That way the CSS will allow a size up to original size (but not larger, which would cause bad quality)